# ElasticSearch find most frequently used words with a given word

Tags: elasticsearch

I have millions of records containing words separated by a comma

e.g: `worda,wordb,wordc,wordd`

For a given word, I need to find out the most frequently used words.

Sample data:

```
love,karachi,june,seaside
karachi,icecream,seaside
hate,new,weekend,karachi,seaside
```

If the input is 'karachi', should return top 'n' terms used with 'karachi'

```
seaside(3)
```

Comment: can you please share your index mapping, some sample data, and your expected result ?

Comment: The data is not indexed yet, it resides in another data source. I have simple rows with one column which contains comma-separated words

Comment: Is the data in this format `"data":["a","b","c"]` ?

Comment: data is in pure string format, please see my latest edit